# Angular2 Routing: redirectTo a dynamically generated string

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-routing, angular2-aot

Per default I need to redirect to today's date. Here is the routing config I have for now:

```
import { CALENDAR_ROUTE } from './_methods/utils';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {
    path: CalendarComponent.path, 
    component: CalendarComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: refDataResolver,
    data: {
      navi: {
        at: 'main',
        icon: 'navbar-calendar'
      },
      roles: {
        employeeOnly: true
      }
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: CALENDAR_ROUTE.DEFAULT_MONTH
      },
      {
        path: LAYOUT_MONTH,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: CALENDAR_ROUTE.MONTH
          },
          {
            path: ':year/:month',
            component: CalendarMonthViewComponent
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: LAYOUT_DAY,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: CALENDAR_ROUTE.DAY
          },
          {
            path: ':year/:month/:day',
            component: CalendarDayViewComponent
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
  ];
```

Here is how I generate the strings in **utils.ts**:

```
import { LAYOUT_MONTH } from './../_classes/const';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export function getRoute(withDay: boolean, prefix?: string): string {
    const now = moment();
    const day = ( withDay ) ? now.format('DD') : null;
    return [prefix, now.format('YYYY'), now.format('MM'), day]
        .filter( str => !!str)
        .join('/');
}

export const CALENDAR_ROUTE = {
    DEFAULT_MONTH: getRoute(false, LAYOUT_MONTH),
    MONTH: getRoute(false),
    DAY: getRoute(true)
};
```

It all goes well - in dev mode and localhost – until I need to compile it for UAT/PROD, which utilizes AOT builds, which then throws a

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule' 
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'getRoute' was called in 'appRoutes' 
'appRoutes' calls 'getRoute' at app/app-routing.module.ts(67,42).
```

I haven't yet found a solution to this problem. There are some issues which would use `providers` and `useValue` - but it feels like an overkill right here. Maybe there is a different kind of a workaround? Maybe I should structure my components differently? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to inject the `Router` into your component and then update the route config at runtime.

I'v not tested this myself, but the idea would be something like this:

In your component

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.config.unshift({path: '', component: '', redirectTo: 'Your new redirect path'})
}
```